# How to prevent other domains from getting images from azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I set up cors in azure storage (URL-for example: [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com), GET, * , *, 200)

[image]

Then i just copy the link from storage

[image]

> https://demo.blob.core.windows.net/demo/demo.png

And use it on postman or localhost (web), but still can display pictures, is it normal?

I suppose postman and localhost website will not be able to get images, once cors is set up for azure storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS prevents cross domain requests that are usually send by AJAX requests. If such a request is send from your browser it will perform a preflight request to see if your current domain is allowed to make such a request. As example it would prevent this site from sending a `POST` request in the background to `api.<yourbank>.com` to transfer money.

It won't stop anybody from embedding an image or other file on their website as the browser won't perform such a preflight request unless they call the resource through an AJAX request. Likewise Postman won't do that as it's a testing tool where you explicitely define the request you want to send without being on another 'domain'.

Comment: So is there any function in azure storage that prevents the acquisition of pictures (such as authentication requests, create if confirmed, otherwise refuse to acquire pictures (even if the picture url is entered, the picture cannot be displayed or downloaded))? Except for creating private blobs with short period SAS

Comment: Using only the storage account you don't have many options. The firewall is the only thing that can really block traffic. If you only want to block reading you could encrypt the files (although that would require decryption on the other end). Another option is using a function app whose only purpose is authenticating the request and redirecting to a SAS with short expiry. That way you can apply any custom authentication logic you like and still have the benefit of allowing your user to directly access the files with very little extra costs.